# Why does this type guard not work on generic parameters?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider the following code ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPAPAFQD4AKANwEMAbENALkXwEp79EBvAKEWWEWJwAOaOLwrU0iALzTEAcgDOUAE4wwAc1mN2XboiVooIJUjE0AdPoGVyENMVnA4cWQBo5AI3JLNAbh0BfHX1DY0RTND9-IA)):

```js
function identity<T>(value: T): T {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return value.replace('foo', 'bar'); // <-- ERROR
  }
  return value;
}
```

It results in the error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.`

It seems that the type guard is not sufficient to narrow the type of the generic parameter and perform a string operation.

Why does this error occur and how would I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the function gets called like this

```
const example: 'foo' = 'foo';

const result = identity(example);
```

According to the type definition of the function, since `T` is `"foo"` (ie, a specific string, not a general `string`), i must be returned a `"foo"` as well. But the code inside the function will return "bar" instead, so it's violating the types.

---

To do what you want, you'll want to use function overloading to give it different types for the string case than for other cases. For example:

```
function identity<T>(value: string): string;
function identity<T>(value: T): T;
function identity<T>(value: T): T | string {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return value.replace('foo', 'bar');
  }
  return value;
}
```

If this code is called with `T` == `"foo"`, then typescript will see that a value of `"foo"` is [compatible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) with `value: string`, so the first type definition for the function matches. According to that type definition, the return value is thus a general `string`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPAPAFQD4AKANwEMAbENALkQGcoAnGMAcwEp6nWOBuAFChIsBMnSYYOAiQrU6ifNyVCR0eElQYseImSo16y44gA+jFm3aIA3oMTJgiYjgAOaOM-k1EAXgDEAHJeayDOOwdHRGY0KBBmJB80ADpYt0pyCDRiIOA4OCCAGmCAI3JmcKFHAF8o2PjExGShOsE2KDRmYCy0RABRAA9yAFsMvvtHKAALa3owEBHSrqLBNogEJkQ0YbHKNABGejyCoP9g-MKhDbAtzqYD8+0pHGId0fGDzn5EAHpfmJoBggShQBjIJDkSx8dglMBwKCIKEAIkuyMEghuW3eezQACYeFYOOcTldMZtEfcoHinpJdG9duM8d8-gDYsDQeC2EjodYMVjETjxvQhh99udbIgZnNEDSatcKVKgVAAMy0nTSbAMsVoFn-QEcsEQpFIUW4oA)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Is there a way to rewrite this function in a way where I can replace text in strings but leave everything else alone in a type-safe way?